# How to write the url patterns. Python, Django

Tags: python, django, url

I need to write URLPatterns for any string(max length - 5) and then pass this URL pattern to function. I tried do this:

```
url(r'^([a-z]{5})$/', open)
```

But it does not work: `page not found`. What I do wrong?

Comment: try `url(r'^([a-z]{5})/$', open)`

Comment: Literally "any string"? Or just lowercase letters?

Comment: f43d65, yes, lowercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^([a-z]{5})/$', open)
```

Swap `/` and `$`.

Answer (score 3):

You are matching string of exactly length 5. Also you are matching only the string including characters a to z. For matching strings of lowercase characters and numbers of length 1 to 5 try something like this:

```
url(r'^([a-z0-9]{1,5})/$', open)
```

For matching string of exactly 5 character length,

```
url(r'^([a-z0-9]{5})/$', open)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need exactly 5 symbols